# What has happend to my TOR-Browser / cryptic letters shown

Tags: linux, firefox, fedora, tor

Since the last TOR-Browser bundle update, the TOR-Browser just displays cryptic letters only.
Just look at the screenshot. What has happend? How to fix that?

TOR-Browser bundle on Fedora 33

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the same problem as described in the bug report of
[Fonts don't render](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40671).

The solution there is:

- Open `tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/fontconfig/fonts.conf`
- Modify line 37 and replace the line  `<dir>fonts</dir>`
  with this:
  `<dir prefix="relative">fonts</dir>`.

If the above doesn't help, try to uninstall TOR-Browser, clean out all
its folders, then clean-install the latest version.

If this also doesn't work, consider staying with the old version that
worked, for the moment, and report the problem on the TOR-Browser forums.

Comment: Yeap, that worked. Thanks a lot.